# Is there a way to know when will a floating-point computation be accurate/inaccurate without actually doing the computation?

Tags: floating-point, ieee-754, floating-accuracy, rounding-error

I understand that floating-point computation is inherently inaccurate due to rounding errors. But how can I understand that it is sometimes accurate, sometimes inaccurate, like the following:

```
In [58]: 0.2+0.2==0.4
Out[58]: True

In [59]: 0.2+0.1==0.3
Out[59]: False
```

I guess this has something to do with the representation of floating-point numbers. Any idea? In particular, when will this be accurate/inaccurate -- Is there a way to know that in advance, namely, without actually doing the computation itself?

Comment: What do you mean by "in advance"? Do you have any prior knowledge about the input numbers? E.g., `x+x` should always be accurate as long as it does not overflow. If you have `x>=y>=0`, you could check if `(x+y) - x == y` to see if `x+y` is accurate.

Comment: If you add two normal numbers with the same sign and exponent whose low bits are different, the result will be inaccurate. If you add two normal numbers with the same sign and exponents that differ by d and the low d bits of the smaller magnitude number are not all zero, the result will be inaccurate. If the sum will cause the result to have a greater exponent than the larger magnitude number and the low d+1 bits of the smaller magnitude number are not all zero, the result will be inaccurate. Other cases (different sign) could be described too. How would this be useful to you?

Comment: Let x and y be the numbers resulting from converting .2 and .1 to IEEE-754 binary64 (a.k.a. “double precision”), respectively. Adding x and x adds two numbers of the same sign and exponent and that have the same low bit, so it does not fall into a case described above. The result is exact. Adding x and y adds two numbers with an exponent difference of 1. (x is in [2^−3, 2^−2), so its exponent is −3. y is in [2^−4, 2^−3), so its exponent is −4.) The result will have a greater exponent (it will be in [2^−2, 2^−1), so its exponent will be − 2). The low 2 bits of y are 10, so they are not zero.

Comment: (Using hexadecimal notation for the significand, x is 0x1.999999999999ap−3, and y is 0x1.999999999999ap−4.)

Comment: zell, unfortunately post code is more than comparing additions.  It is also comparing conversion of code like `0.4` into `double`, which is often inexact.  Try improving your post and use _exact_ FP values like 0.125, 0x1234p-4, ... to ask you question.  I think you will find your concerns are not addition ones, but code conversion to `double` ones.